# CakePHP radio button and input field

Tags: forms, cakephp

I'm looking to create a rather complex form in CakePHP where the user is presented with radio buttons which have input boxes instead of labels, essentially outputting the following:

```
<input type="radio" val="1" /><input type="text"  />
<br />
<input type="radio" val="2" /><input type="text"  />
<br />
<input type="radio" val="3" /><input type="text"  />
<br />
<input type="radio" val="4" /><input type="text"  />
```

I'd like to use FormHelper as I'm using SecurityComponent and there are issues with it if you use non-Cake forms.

Comment: you can use `div => false` and `label => null` in form helper.

Comment: i think you have to add manually. form helper will not support like this

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:**

You can't do that with the FormHelper.

**More detail:**

I'm sure there are a LOT of ways to do whatever your doing - but the answer boils down to the TLDR above.  So, just make sure you manually (not FormHelper) create the fields you don't want submitted, then remove them prior to submit, and you should be good.  Any linking between the two can easily be done with javascript.